# Conditional rendering error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, rendering

I have a problem when conditional rendering a component in react native.
it shows me this error message:

> JavascriptException: {"stack":"Error: failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

And here's an example of my code principe

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        {this.customRender()}
    );
  }

  customRender() {
    var x = true;
    if(x) {
        return (<View />);
    }
    else return (<Text>False</Text>);
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this thread helps you? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6035

Comment: Can you take this error on debug environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys i fixed the problem.
First i disabled the Remote debugging, after that the error message changed and now it shows that i have a syntax error in the render method, precisely in the return, so i changed this:

```
return({this.customRender()});
```

to this

```
return(this.customRender());
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

One problem could have nothing to do with the code, but it is a result of your application using the bundled JS-File in development mode. You should use the packager for the development and the normal bundled files for production usage. You can open the web browser with the "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag to use the bundled version in the development setting.

Another possible problem could be the self-closing `View`-Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check the packager log, it's likely that you have a syntax error somewhere in your code, probably something very simple like a missing comma. Run a linter on your code, it will help you find the error if the error message frmo the packager log isn't helpful.