# React / AFrame object assign error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aframe

Am attempting to hook up Aframe inside react-native, but when launching in the emulator I get this error:

```
One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. Are you trying to assign a prototype property? We don't allow it, as this is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and no spec compliant.
```

I'm using Aframe 0.5.0 and React-Native 0.41.2

The error is thrown from line 56 of polyfills.js, and relates to this section of aframe-master.js:55729.

```
Object.assign( THREE.MTLLoader.prototype, THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype, {
```

Is there any way around this? Do I need to modify aframe to use a different assignment, or is there some way I can get past this?

I'm running a very simple hello world, it's failing just trying to load the dependencies. In other related issues people have said they've gotten around it by using lodash.assign or Object.defineProperties - is this a viable solution for this? I can revert to an older version of react-native in the meantime but I'd ideally like to use the latest with a-frame.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5507

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3634

** UPDATE ** 
Ok I tried rolling back, installed react-native 0.36.1 and switched the site I'm loading in the WebView to use aframe 0.3.2.

The code I have in the React native app is this:

Ok I tried rolling back, installed react-native 0.36.1 using rninit, and switched the site I'm loading in the WebView to use aframe 0.3.2.

The code I have in the React native app is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 // import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import {
   AppRegistry,
   WebView
 } from 'react-native';

 export default class test4 extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <WebView source={{uri: 'http://[theurl]/test.html'}}/>
     );
   }
 }


 AppRegistry.registerComponent('test4', () => test4);
```

The aframe app is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A-Frame walkthrough (final)</title>
        <script src="/aframe.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <img id="circle" src="circle.png"/>
    </a-assets>


      <a-sky src="Ephesus4_1.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>

</html>
```

And when I open up the debugger by inspecting the webview from the chrome://inspect#devices, I get this output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Android SDK built for x86_64 Build/MASTER; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119 Mobile Safari/537.36
aframe.js:54681 Recalculating device params.
aframe.js:54718 User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Android SDK built for x86_64 Build/MASTER; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119 Mobile Safari/537.36
aframe.js:54719 Pixel width: 2562
aframe.js:54720 Pixel height: 1442
aframe.js:54762 No DPDB device match.
aframe.js:54683 New device parameters:
aframe.js:54684 null
aframe.js:54692 Failed to recalculate device parameters.Dpdb.recalculateDeviceParams_ @ aframe.js:54692
aframe.js:54654 Fetching DPDB...
aframe.js:53106 Using fallback Android device measurements.
aframe.js:56388 Failed to load viewer profile: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null
    at Emitter.ViewerSelector (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:56386:36)
    at VRDisplay.CardboardVRDisplay (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:52607:26)
    at WebVRPolyfill.populateDevices (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:56694:17)
    at WebVRPolyfill.getVRDisplays (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:56743:8)
    at new THREE.VRControls (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:66848:13)
    at Object.119.../lib/three (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:66227:16)
    at s (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:1:620)
    at http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:1:671
    at Object.122../bind (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:66358:25)
    at s (http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/aframe.js:1:620)ViewerSelector @ aframe.js:56388
aframe.js:53096 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distortionCoefficients' of undefined
aframe.js:54662 Successfully loaded online DPDB.
aframe.js:54681 Recalculating device params.
aframe.js:54718 User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Android SDK built for x86_64 Build/MASTER; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119 Mobile Safari/537.36
aframe.js:54719 Pixel width: 2562
aframe.js:54720 Pixel height: 1442
aframe.js:54762 No DPDB device match.
aframe.js:54683 New device parameters:
aframe.js:54684 null
aframe.js:54692 Failed to recalculate device parameters.Dpdb.recalculateDeviceParams_ @ aframe.js:54692
http://ec2-52-62-186-186.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated!

I'm also getting this in the android emulator itself:

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException:{"stack":"Error: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false' failed to load.\n at executeApplicationScript (http://localhost:8081/ebuggerWorker.js:207)\n at onmessage (http://localhost:8081/debuggerWorker.js:38.5)"}

I get the same error even if I switch to a non aframe site being loaded in the webview.

Comment: Hi Toby, could you post the version of reactjs and aframe you are using?

Comment: Yep Aframe 0.5.0 and React-native 0.41.2, have added to the question

Comment: My successful deployment used aframe 0.3.2 and React-native 0.36.1. I'd recommend you to downgrade for testing. Also based on your research the problem seems to related more on react-native end. Have you tried to load the native webview in your app instead of the react one?

Comment: Hi Tony, Great troubleshooting. Have you test native webview on simulator? How about on real device?

Comment: Haven't tested on a real device yet, will try that today, but I'm using the native WebView - I've removed all reference to aframe from the react native app itself. If you have time, would love to organise a chat and pick your brain about how you got your solution working?

Comment: @ChrisChen do you know what version of react itself you were using? I just told rninit to install react-native version 0.36.1 and it has react 15.3.2 installed alongside.

Comment: Testing on a Pixel XL, trying to load the aframe app via a webview results in an empty screen, and eventually the app crashes. No apparent errors on screen or in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe this is your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088268/conditional-rendering-error-in-react-native. The aframe logs is only throwing warnings, don't think it is the main cause of the app crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing about, I discovered that a lot of my issues were due to trying to test in the simulator.

When running on the device I was able to get an app running the latest version of a-frame working with the latest version of react-native, but only by setting up react-native to recompile the android project from source java, pulling from the current master.

I also had to enable hardware acceleration in the Android.Manifest.

Thanks to Chris Chen for the assist